# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.admin.TopicCommand

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to create topic in kafka. Here is my command.

> .\bin\kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --create --topic myTopic --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1

But I get an exception while create topic `caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.admin.TopicCommand`. My kafka version is a `3.3.1` and `kafka-topics.sh` is located at `C:\kafka_2.13-3.3.1\bin` path.

Here is my `kafka-topics.sh` file

```
#!/bin/bash
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
# 
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
# 
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

exec $(dirname $0)/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.admin.TopicCommand "$@"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is solved. Instead of run a `kafka-topics.sh`, I run a `kafka-topics.bat` file. Which is located at `C:\kafka_2.13-3.3.1\bin\windows`.

Here is my new command

> .\bin\windows\kafka-topics.bat --create --topic myTopic --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1